# Nativescript firebase vibration when app in background

Tags: firebase, push-notification, nativescript, firebase-cloud-messaging

When app in background, firebase plugin not calling **onMassageReceived** and I can't add vibration, when notification received. How I can solve that?

```
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
var vibrator = require("nativescript-vibrate");

firebase.init({
    url: AppUrl
}).then(
    (instance) => {
        console.log("firebase.init done true");
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);

firebase.addOnMessageReceivedCallback((message:any)=>{
    vibrator.vibration(500);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It would be nice to edit your question and add the code you've written so far : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this plugin requires some modification on files located in platforms folder. However if you rebuild your app the platform folder will be overwritten so make sure your settings are still there before running the app. Also you can try to pass the callback implementation in the init fnction (e.g. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo/blob/master/Firebase/app/main-view-model.js)

Comment: What type of message are you sending? Notification message or Data message. If you are sending from the Firebase console then you are sending a Notification message.

Comment: May be create service and call method from service to vibrate when app is killed/minimized.